# Parent-Child Data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, linq, cursor

I have a following structure in SQL server.

```
ID    EmpID    Address   IsPrimary   PrimaryID    AddressType
--------------------------------------------------------------
1      1       <abc>        No           2            1
2      1       <abc>        No           3            1
3      1       <abc>       Yes          NULL          1
4      1       <abc>       Yes          NULL          2
```

Consider that, for Empid 1 I will show IsPrimary records of Emp in Parent Grid. When I click on the row, I will pass EmpId and ID and I want to get the records in below format.

If I pass 3, then I should get Ids 1,2
If I pass 4, then I should get Ids 4 alone.

Logic is:

1. Initially ID 1 was the primary (that time, Isprimary is 'Yes' and PrimaryId is NULL)
2. Next, primary address got changed to ID 2 (so record one has IsPrimary as 'No' and PrimaryId as 2)
3. Later it again changed to Id 3. Now record with 3 is primary record.

in 4th case, (for address type 2) is the only primary record).

How to achieve this by writing query??? any help will be appreicated. :)

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far?  Also, it would help to have expected results.

Comment: Look at the hierarchical queries.  In SQL server this is typically accomplished using CTE's or For XML path.  Which one are you trying to use?

Comment: I am trying to use CTE and in the worst case, I plan to go for Cursors.. Though it is not recommented... :(